# I use three.js replacement mesh material, the results of the update is completed, png transparent part of the picture into a black

Tags: three.js

I use three.js replacement mesh material, the results of the update is completed, png transparent part of the picture into a black? I can not find something about this , can you help me ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmRUB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add material :  alphaTest: 0.5  ; then it is ok.